# Marshalling nested objects to a "flat" XML structure

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How might I marshall an object hierarchy such that, instead of having the component objects becoming nested XML elements, their properties become direct children of the root element with their names prefixed by their type.

For example, given:

```
                                                    (A)
public class Customer {

    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected Address address;
}

public class Address {

    protected String street;
    protected String city;
}
```

Using the usual JAXB annotations would result in

```
                                                    (B)
<customer>
    <firstName>Juan</firstName>
    <lastName>dela Cruz</lastName>
    <address>
        <street>123 Rizal Avenue</street>
        <city>Manila</city>
    </address>
</customer>
```

But, instead, I need to marshall the same as

```
                                                    (C)
<customer>
    <firstName>Juan</firstName>
    <lastName>dela Cruz</lastName>
    <address_street>123 Rizal Avenue</address_street>
    <address_city>Manila</address_city>
</customer>
```

It would be great if there were some JAXB incantation to solve my needs since I'm already using JAXB for most of the things around this problem. In fact, these present some constraints to my specific situation:

1. The Java classes in **(A)** are generated by JAXB from an existing schema that corresponds to the XML structure in **(B)**. I would prefer not to maintain modified versions of the generated classes.
2. I do not own or maintain the said schema. The actual schema is quite large and is often subject to minor modifications. It would be tedious to come up with and maintain an equivalent schema. Also, to keep up with schema modifications, I rely on the automated class generation by JAXB.
3. If it makes things easier, nesting is only up to one level deep. In the example, `Address` would not contain any other complex type.

I'm looking at the `@XmlPath` annotation from MOXy, but I can't figure out how to get the node names prefixed as in **(C)**.

I dream of a solution where some xjc customizations providing the right JAXB annotations get me going, but that's looking unlikely from my searches so far. Any non-JAXB solution would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using an [XStream Converter](https://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html). It checks for the `@XmlType` annotation to determine if a JAXB bean is being converted. All other types go through the default converters.

Though a JAXB-centric solution would have been nice, XStream provided a compellingly straightforward solution.

```
public class FlatXmlConverter implements Converter {

    private static final Logger log =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(NvpConverter.class);

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
            MarshallingContext context) {
        Class<? extends Object> sourceClass = source.getClass();
        String prefix = (String) context.get("prefix");
        for (Field field : sourceClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (!field.isAccessible()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }
            String name = field.getName();
            Class<?> type = field.getType();

            try {
                Object value = field.get(source);
                if (value != null) {
                    if (type.isAnnotationPresent(XmlType.class)) {
                        context.put("prefix", name);
                        context.convertAnother(value);
                        context.put("prefix", null);
                    } else {
                        String nodeName;
                        if (prefix == null) {
                            nodeName = name;
                        } else {
                            nodeName = prefix + "_" + name;
                        }

                        writer.startNode(nodeName);
                        context.convertAnother(value);
                        writer.endNode();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                log.error("IllegalArgumentException", ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                log.error("IllegalAccessException", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        log.debug("canConvert({})", type);
        return type.isAnnotationPresent(XmlType.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You can use the external mapping file in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) to apply a second mapping to your object model, and the `@XmlPath` extension to flatten the object model.

**External Mapping File (oxm.xml)**

The following is what the external mapping file might look like if your model classes where in a package called `forum11007814`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum11007814"
    xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Customer">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="address" xml-path="."/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Address">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="street" name="address_street"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="city" name="address_city"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Demo**

Below is code that demonstrates how to leverage MOXy's external mapping file when creating the `JAXBContext`.

```
package forum11007814;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String,Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "forum11007814/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Customer.class}, properties);

        File xml = new File("src/forum11007814/c.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**c.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
   <firstName>Juan</firstName>
   <lastName>dela Cruz</lastName>
   <address_street>123 Rizal Avenue</address_street>
   <address_city>Manila</address_city>
</customer>
```

Comment: I'm a bit wary of having to write another xml file for the mapping. The XSD where the original classes are coming from is already quite large and it would seem the mapping for such would be equivalently large.

Considering that the mapping I need is mechanical, is there a way, in MOXy, to provide these mappings programatically?

Comment: @Edward - Here the mapping file is only needed to override metadata, so I would anticipate that it would be much smaller that the original XSD.  There are hooks such as `@XmlCustomizer` and `SessionEventListener` that let you get a handle on the underlying metadata and modify it programmatically.

Comment: You lost me at [@XmlCustomizer](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/annotations/XmlCustomizer.html) and [SessionEventListener](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/SessionEventListener.html) (am I even looking at the right places?) I've never used MOXy before. I may take a while to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no standard way of doing this. What you can do is create two java classes, one with the hierarchical structure, one with the flat structure, and use java introspection to copy the data from one into the other, then use the second to create the xml.

Comment: As I mentioned, the classes are automatically generated from a fairly large XML schema. So manually maintaining a second set of classes would be prohibitive. Also, by the time I get into writing reflective code, I'd just as well be writing out the XML I wanted instead of writing to another class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am the creator of juffrou-xml which enables you to do that in a simple way: just configure this in xml-mapping file:

```
<root-element xml="Customer" type="org.yourpackage.Customer">
  <element property="firstName" />
  <element property="lastName" />
  <element property="address.street" xml="address_street"/>
  <element property="address.city" xml="address_city"/>
</root-element>

<root-element xml="Address" type="org.yourpackage.Address" />
```

Marshalling nested beans to a flat XML struture is easy this way. And the other way around - unmarshalling - will create the object graph as expected.

Check out Juffrou-XML [here](http://juffrou.sourceforge.net/juffrou-xml).

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked JiBX (tool for binding XML data to Java objects)?
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/binding/tutorial/binding-structures.html

Answer (score -1):

Use @XmlID a @XmlIDREF.
And make class with list of all objects.